# What is the best way to achieve updating a DOM element with vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have a a div that does the following using vanilla javascript:

1. Fades out completely
2. Updates with new content
3. Positions to new screen coordinates
4. Fades back in

Cancelling fades mid way through also, so if a user clicks a button 20 times quickly, it doesn't fade in/fade out 20 times, just the most recent time.

Here is where I'm at right now:
https://jsfiddle.net/d685Ledu/

```
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <p>Content content</p>
  </div>

  <button id="button">click me</button>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript">
var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
var fadeSpeed = 0.01;

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
  fadeOut();
  updateDiv();
  moveDiv();
  fadeIn();
});

function updateDiv() {
    wrapper.innerHTML= '<div>lots</div><div>of</div><div>new</div><div>content</div>';
}

function moveDiv() {
  wrapper.style.top = '100px';
  wrapper.style.left = '100px';
}

function fadeIn() {
    var opacity = 0;

  function increase() {
    opacity += fadeSpeed;
    if (opacity >= 1){
     wrapper.style.opacity = 1;
     return true;
     }
     wrapper.style.opacity = opacity;
     requestAnimationFrame(increase);
  }

  increase();
}

function fadeOut() {
    var opacity = 1;

    function decrease() {
    opacity -= fadeSpeed;
    if (opacity <= 0){
      wrapper.style.opacity = 0;
      return true;
    }
    wrapper.style.opacity = opacity;
    requestAnimationFrame(decrease);
  }
    decrease();
}

</script>
```

What is the most idiomatic way to achieve this?

Comment: doesn't your JSFiddle do all of this already?  what exactly do you need help with?

Comment: The CSS style doesn't look like it's applied.

Comment: You're doing "wrapper.innerHTML="...."", meaning that you're setting the inner properties of the div. As such, the div's `style` attribute is being overwritten .

Comment: @FuriousFolder ah yes, but even when i change the inner html to include a wrapper div with id of "wrapper" it doesn't work

Comment: Long story short: It's a bad idea to manually edit the HTML like this unless you have an *extremely* good reason to do so. I *strongly* suggest you use a framework, like jquery or ExtJS. It will give you much finer control over your webpage.

Comment: Erg.. scratch my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `margin-left` and `margin-right` if you're simply trying to update that specific div.

That being said, change your `moveDiv` function to:

```
 function moveDiv() {   
  wrapper.style["margin-left"]="100px";
  wrapper.style["margin-top"]="100px";
}
```

Like I said in my second comment, I highly suggest you look into a framework.

[Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/m6wjthcg/)

Comment: Cool thanks. I'm building little things without frameworks specifically to learn so a framework is out of the question, but thanks for the suggestion. I guess I could try my hand at looking at jQuery fade code.